Find words with numbers but replace only number
In Notepad++, how to find all words with alloy and replace only the number after it with 0?
Although there are cases they need be replaced with 1.
The replacement is on per file basis so 0 and 1 will not appear on the same edited XML file.
Example data:
adhesive 36, refined_tungsten_alloy 4, 
steel 32, refined_tungsten_alloy 376,
thread 24, refined_aluminium_alloy 5, thread 36, refined_aluminium_alloy 10,


What is your expected result? Replace numbers with what?

@SuperDngBzz, please add in question, not as comment. And describe when to replace with 1 and when with 0


Ctrl+H
Find what: _alloy \K\d+
Replace with: 0 or 1 depending on file.
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

Explanation:
_alloy          # literally with a space at the end
\K              # match reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position
\d+             # 1 or more digits

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):

